# unable to fetch system.int64 registry datavalue in powershell

Tags: powershell

Below powershell code is for exporting the complete registry hive to CSV file. But it gives error for exporting REG_Binary type data whose value is big as shown in the attached registry screenshot.  Though I tried to convert it to string but no luck. Please suggest on how to fetch the REG_Binary data or how to convert it to string.

```
Function Get_Reg_Keys ($reg_key) {
    $actualKey = Get-Item -Path Registry::$reg_key
    #Write-Host $actualKey 
    ForEach ($name in $actualKey.GetValueNames()) { 
        # Write-Host $name
        $name.Property | foreach {
            $type = $actualKey.GetValue($name).GetType()
            #Write-Host $type
            Write-Host $actualKey.Name " | " $name " | " $actualKey.GetValue($name) " | " $type 

            If ( $type -eq [System.Byte[]] -Or $type -eq [System.Int64[]]) {    
                $a = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($actualKey.GetValue($name))
                ( '"{0:0}","{1:0}", "{2:0}"' -f $actualKey.Name, $name, $a) | 
                    Out-File  "C:\Temp\Automation\HKCU.csv" -append -Encoding ascii -erroraction SilentlyContinue
            }
            Else {
                ( '"{0:0}","{1:0}", "{2:0}"' -f $actualKey.Name, $name, $actualKey.GetValue($name)) | 
                    Out-File  "C:\Temp\Automation\HKCU.csv" -append -Encoding ascii -erroraction SilentlyContinue
            }
        }
    }

    $keyinfo = Get-ChildItem Registry::$reg_key
    if ($keyinfo.count -gt 0) {

        ForEach ($keyitem in $keyinfo) { Get_Reg_Keys ($keyitem)  }
    }
}
```

Then running: `Get_Reg_Keys ("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\")`

Gives the error:

```
Cannot convert argument "index", with value: "MRUListEx", for "GetValue" to type "System.Int64": "Cannot convert value "MRUListEx" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was 
not in a correct format.""
At C:\Temp\Automation\HKCUregistrynew.ps1:27 char:21
+                     ( '"{0:0}","{1:0}", "{2:0}"' -f $actualKey.Name, $name, $act ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Registry Key details:
[image: registrykeydetails]

Comment: If I wanted to export a hive, I'd use ```reg.exe``` instead of trying to write something myself in Powershell. For example, the following exports the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive to a test file named hkcu_export.reg in the current directory: ```reg export hkcu .\hkcu_export.reg``` You can use this to search the registry or import that hive to another location.

Comment: When you add parameters to a function in powershell, I'd use the Param() syntax (see Get-Help about_functions_advanced).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm having a tough time following your function. I'm not even sure how you're iterating over values in a key with that `$name.properties | foreach...` loop.

But, generally, this is pretty straight forward. For example, I've got a registry key `HKCU:\Environment`. I've created a property in that key named "thing", and I've stuffed it with some random binary data.

[image]

I'll take the guts of that property and output it to a file:

```
$reg_key = 'HKCU:\Environment'
$key_properties = Get-Item -Path $reg_key
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($key_properties.GetValue('thing')) | Out-File -FilePath .\Test.txt
cat .\Test.txt
```

Just to show there is nothing up my sleeve:

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Lord, thanks for your reply but the REG_Binary value which you have given is pretty small. Please refer the Reg_Binary value in my screenshot.

Comment: You can refer the hive: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU\*]

Comment: The size of the value does not matter. It will work for any size binary value.

Answer (score 0):

After making below changes I am able to export a registry hive to CSV file:
 $actualKey = Get-Item -LiteralPath Registry::$reg_key

$keyinfo = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath Registry::$reg_key